# Computing the complexity of a function that contains two consecutive functions

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

If we have an algorithm `x` that includes two sequential functions, the complexity of the first is `f(n)` and the second is `g(n)`, what is the complexity of algorithm `x`?

Ex:

```
x(x){
  f(n);
  g(n)
}
```

is it `Max(f(n),g(n))`, `g(n)+f(n)` or something else?

Comment: Assuming f and g are positive, O(f+g)=O(max(f, g)). Because f+g < 2max(f, g), and max(f, g) < f + g